# How can I enable notifications from games/apps?

Tags: 8.1, settings, notifications

I own a Nokia Lumia 530 and I have been using it a lot. But what I've noticed is that I don't receive notifications. Instead I have to check apps now and again. My brother got one too just recently and it receives notifications perfectly.

How can I enable notifications on my phone?

Comment: Have you checked if there is an in-app setting to control notifications? Also, do you have Battery Saver turned on?

Comment: Active all the apps and games instantly

Answer (score 1):

First, go to Battery Saver app and make sure that the apps you want to receive notifications from are allowed to run in background(This information is showed below the name of the app). If not, allow it by tapping in the app and changing the switch to "Activated". Then you need to open those apps and look for a notification check box, and check the ones you want.
Remember that Windows Phone 8.1 has a limit of 20 apps running in background for devices with 512 MB of RAM.

Comment: I see no such option. Sl I see is how much battery apps are taking and there are no options. I've looked in notifications and actions and it only shows the basic wifi mail and other apps that the phone cokes with, although they don't notify either.

Comment: I'm using my phone to type. Stupid autocorrect/\

Comment: "has a limit of 20 apps running in background" You sure it's not only for 512MB phones?

Comment: @ColtonLeseman The answer was edited with more information of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 8.1, you can go to Settings>Notifications+actions. Here, you can see your list of apps installed. By selecting each of the apps, you see options that can be modified to enable or disable notifications as well as selecting notification sound, etc.

[image]
[image]